# friend function returning reference to private data member

Tags: c++, oop, reference, constants

I have two questions about the following code.

```
class cls{
    int vi;
    public:
        cls(int v=37) { vi=v; }
        friend int& f(cls);
};

int& f(cls c) { return c.vi; }

int main(){
    const cls d(15);
    f(d)=8;
    cout<<f(d);
    return 0;
}
```

1. Why does it compile, since f(d) = 8 attemps to modify a const object?
2. Why does it still print 15, even after removing the const attribute?

Comment: I am confused. What attribute is const?

Comment: Const is an attribute. d (in main) is a const object, but as hmdj pointed out, it is passed by value in f, so a temporary object's vi is modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not modifying a `const` object as a *copy* of `d` is being made due to the argument of `f()` being passed by value and not by reference. This is also the reason that `d` is unchanged as it is not being modified.